# Magento - CSS compilation

Tags: php, css, magento, content-management-system

I changed some CSS styles of [the theme](http://demo.magentech.com/themes/sm_maxshop/) locally but when try to hosting some styles backed to the default!

It seems that it compile some default CSS files.

I have these folders that have CSS files

```
base/
default/
rwd/
sm-maxshop/
```

How can I stop overwriting my styles!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Delete LESS files

2- Upload CSS files again

3- Flush CSS cache

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go To Your Store Admin pannel Then In Configuration Click On Developer Tab. After that click on CSS setting and Disable the Merge CSS Files. Again Upload your changes and you successfully uploaded enable the option again. Also Clear your CSS cache.

Comment: I did but seems like nothing changed